# What is the best method to add multiple duplicate faces to an existing face

Tags: edit-mode

I want to reproduce the 'look' of a small building which has 14 glass 'windows' in the front wall - refer to photo image below.
For the purposes of this consider a simple mesh rectangular cube to represent the rectangular building and one face representing the front 'panel'.

I considered using another rectangular mesh, position it where I want each of the windows and then 'cut a hole' at each window position using the boolean modifier but that didn't seem to be the answer.

I then created a material image with a grid of lines to add to the front face and then use the knife tool to add cuts along the appropriate grid lines but that looked like too much work and there should be an easier method.

I don't want to use loop cuts as I only want the cuts on the front face.

I want to end up with 15 'faces' - the original face and 14 smaller 'internal' faces which I can add a material set up for glass.
I hope I have made it clear to the reader what I want to achieve.
Can anyone suggest how I can do this? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you plan to extrude inwards all the windows you can create as many loopcuts as necessary then X > Limited DIssolve to dissolve most of them, if you don't need to extrude then just use a mask to mix 2 shaders, one for the wall, the other for the glass window, in that case you don't even need additional faces, just one for the whole facade

Comment: Thanks moonboots.  The idea of loop cuts and then diss0olve but I wondered if there was a method which didn't require that. I do want glass 'effect' (alpha channel etc etc). I have not yet used shaders but will see what tutorials I can find on Youtube.

Comment: If you want 3D yes you'll need loopcuts, I'm not sure why you don't want them as you'll dissolve anyway (you'll still have some edges though, you can't create holes without edges connecting the inner edges with the outer edges)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project the image onto the surface of your object, create some loopcuts that are aligned with the windows and extrude inwards:

[image]

Then select all and press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*, here is the result (you can't get rid of all these edges, Blender still need some edges connecting the inner edges with the outer edges):

[image]

Comment: Thanks Moonboots. I will give that a go. Thanks once again for brining my knowledge to limited dissolve.  I should look more carefully at all the options displayed and try them out to0 see what they do.

Comment: Added later.  using loop cuts when I attempt to move the cut it not only allows me to drag the edge left or right it also causes the material I assigned to the face to distort. Should I start a new question? I have attached the blender file to the question above (yes still working on my shed). Also if I try to create edges using the knife toll and press A to cut orthogonally the line draw is NOT perpendicular.

Comment: Maybe easier to add a new rectangular mesh cube for each window. If I want see through glass windows I would have to cut holes using boolean and then select the edges and Fill to create a face for the 'glass' material. Sounds like a lot of work.?

Comment: Silly me. I didn't use GG before dragging the loop cut.

Comment: If you move an edge and don't want texture distortion, activate the Correct Face Attributes option in the top right Options panel. As for the knife it will cut orthogonally with A relatively to your view

Comment: Thanks moonboots

Comment: I also note that not all of the newly created edges can be removed as you state and as I found out. I have now got all my loop cuts selected all the faces which aren't 'windows' and applied the correct material image for the door and then selected all the windows and applied my 'glass' material and it looks great.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add loop cuts, the wall face will result in a n-gon. But that could no matter.

Let's say this is the windows part, selected here, and the wall behind:

[image]

Enter edit mode for the windows, and select the outer part:

[image]

Come back to object mode, select the wall and go in edit mode for it.

Still in edit mode, select the windows using the outliner.

[image]

Now use 'knife projet' from the 'mesh' menu:

[image]

The 'knife project' tool will make a cut in the wall part using the selected edges of the windows part.

This will result in:

[image]

You can now delete the face that correspond to the windows. Join the two objects and merge by distance in edit mode.

[image]

Comment: I will start using loop cuts as I am familiar with them. As I want the distance between the side and the first window half that of the distance between each window (7 windows) I need to do some calculations as I don't want the distance between each widow the same as the width of each window (I hope I explained that correctly). It's 'complicated' (ie distance between each window less than the width of each window  and the outside distance half.

Comment: Dissolving will most likely result in the same kind of faces as knife project. But yes, do it the way you prefer.

Comment: I think that the width of each window is 3 times that of the distance between each window, so its just down to maths I guess in calculation number of cuts.

Comment: Sure... but knife project allows to do the job for 'any' shape of windows and with no calculation...

Comment: 100% correct. Problem was that I didn't want to guess where to place the knife cuts so have considered creating an image (for material) with a grid embedded (something I can do with Paint Shop Pro) and then using that as a material just so that I could know where to place the knife cuts and then replace that 'grid' material with a correct one. I still would have ended up with more edges than I needed and hence the reason for the original post/question.  Thanks again moonboots and lemon. I did though pick up some things I didn't know before from your replies.